# JS class not applying on datapicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

Good morning,

I've got some javascript to check if inputs are empty before printing and if so, cancel the print.

I have added jquery datepicker to one of the fields as a class and now it only applies one class or the other. (I have tried the datepicker as an ID instead) but doesn't work.

Javascript:

```
function checkForm(thisForm) {
var len = thisForm.elements.length ;
var cnt = 0 ;
for ( var i=0; i < len; i++) {
   var elem = thisForm.elements[i] ;
   if (elem.className == "formFieldRequired") {
      if ((elem.value == "" || elem.value == -1)) {
                     alert("WARNING:\n You must supply information for the " + elem.name + " field");
                                elem.focus();
                                return false;
                  }
   }
}
window.print();return true;
}
```

Input:

```
<input name="Effective Date" type="text" style="width:12%;" class="formFieldRequired datepicker" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" onkeyup="javascript:return mask(this.value,this,'2,5','/');" maxlength="10">
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and any fixes? - I may be missing something completely obvious!

Comment: `element.className` will be `"formFieldRequired datepicker"`, not `"formFieldRequired"`.

Comment: I've changed as per your suggestion, however when I print without inputting anything into my form it will print and disregard all other 'formFieldRequired' and "formFieldRequired datepicker" classes

Comment: try `if (Array.prototype.some.call(thisForm.elements, e => e.className && e.className.match(/formFieldRequired/i) && !e.value)) { return false; }` (that will replace the loop).

Comment: Thanks for the help Aluan, I've tried putting that in but I can't seem to get it to work (I am pretty new at this, so that could be the problem!) could you please tell me exactly what should be replaced with this code?

Comment: You can use the `children` property of the form element to get the inputs. I suggest `Array.prototype.some` which tells you if an `Array` contains an element matching the specified predicate function (for example: `e => true`). Because node lists are not really arrays, we have to use `.call`. Get rid of the loop.

Comment: This just proves how new I am to this - what you have said has completely gone over my head! The javascript code works fine until I input the datapicker class. Even if I put in the datapicker linked to the ID so the only class is "formFieldRequired" the error no longer works

Comment: Well, I'm equally at a loss to understand _"Even if I put in the datapicker linked to the ID so the only class is "formFieldRequired" the error no longer works"_

Comment: I use the following code for jquery's datepicker - `$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });` and then use this id for the input. The class is then 'formFieldRequired' - however if I leave this field blank and click print, the checkForm Function will not register the field is blank and return the alert. This problem only happens once the datapicker id has been added.

Comment: Consider using `jQuery` to validate the form. `$(thisForm).find('input').filter(e => e.value === '' || e.value === null).toArray()` would get an array of all form fields without a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
<input name="Effective Date" type="text" style="width:12%;" class="formFieldRequired datepicker" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" onkeyup="javascript:return mask(this.value,this,'2,5','/');" maxlength="10">
</form>

<script>
    function checkForm(thisForm) {
        var len = thisForm.elements.length;
        var cnt = 0 ;
        for ( var i=0; i < len; i++) {
            var elem = thisForm.elements[i] ;
            console.log(elem.className)
            if (elem.className.indexOf("formFieldRequired") != -1)  {
                if ((elem.value == "" || elem.value == -1)) {
                    alert("WARNING:\n You must supply information for the " + elem.name + " field");
                    elem.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        window.print();return true;
    }           

    checkForm(document.getElementById("myform"));
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect, this sorted it out. Thanks very much!